# How can I create a view for my desired output

Tags: mysql, sql, select, view

What should I include in my view so that it outputs number of transactions in September for employee id 4:

```
SELECT * FROM DeniseTransactions;
```

gives the output:

[image]

```
  CREATE TABLE Transactions(
    e_id INT,
    c_id INT,
    l_id INT,
    date DATE,
    t_id INT,
    PRIMARY KEY(t_id),  
    FOREIGN KEY(c_id) references Customers(c_id),
    FOREIGN KEY(e_id) references Employees(e_id),
    FOREIGN KEY(l_id) references Locations(l_id)
    );

    INSERT INTO Transactions VALUES(1,3,1,'2021-08-09',1);
    INSERT INTO Transactions VALUES(4,2,2,'2021-08-14',2);
    INSERT INTO Transactions VALUES(4,4,1,'2021-09-07',3);
    INSERT INTO Transactions VALUES(3,4,1,'2021-09-07',4);
    INSERT INTO Transactions VALUES(4,1,3,'2021-09-07',5);
    INSERT INTO Transactions VALUES(1,4,1,'2021-09-23',6);
```

I know its incorrect but this is what i have so far. Just struggling to get further

```
CREATE VIEW DeniseTransactions AS
    SELECT COUNT(transactions)
    FROM Transactions
    WHERE e_id = '4';
```

Comment: You seem to have accidentally deleted most of your question, especially the details. I will undo that for you. If you want to remove something be more careful please and make sure that the question ends up being according to [ask]. However, please do not remove anything which is needed to make the question answerable, not even after you got your answer.

Answer (score 0):

you need to do `count(*)`:

```
CREATE VIEW DeniseTransactions AS
    SELECT COUNT(*) number_of_transactions
    FROM Transactions
    WHERE e_id = '4'
    AND date >= '2021-09-01' AND date < '2021-10-01';
```

Comment: thanks, how can i create a title for the table like in the linked picture?

Comment: in addition, how can i ensure  that only September transactions are recorded

Comment: @HarrisonB just give it an alias and add the date comparison into your condition./ see updated answer

Answer (score 0):

You can create the view as:

```
create view DeniseTransactions as
select count(*) as number_of_transactions
from Transactions
where t_id = 4
  and date >= '2021-09-01' and date < '2021-10-01';
```

Result:

```
number_of_transactions
----------------------
1
```

See running example at [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kc57Mngw6aeRCUVx5U4AUg/1).